# How to use semantic ui dropdown inside angular *ngFor

Tags: angular, semantic-ui

Semantic ui dropdown works fine outside *ngFor but inside *ngFor it does not work. Is there solution to fix it?

```
<div *ngFor="let task of taskList">
  <div class="ui fluid multiple search selection dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="country">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Select Country</div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item" data-value="af"><i class="af flag"></i>Afghanistan</div>
      <div class="item" data-value="ax"><i class="ax flag"></i>Aland Islands</div>
      <div class="item" data-value="al"><i class="al flag"></i>Albania</div>
      <div class="item" data-value="dz"><i class="dz flag"></i>Algeria</div>
      <div class="item" data-value="as"><i class="as flag"></i>American Samoa</div>
      <div class="item" data-value="zm"><i class="zm flag"></i>Zambia</div>
      <div class="item" data-value="zw"><i class="zw flag"></i>Zimbabwe</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you using **ng2-semantic-ui** for Semantic UI Javascript side?

If you dont, install:

> ```
> npm install --save ng2-semantic-ui
> ```

And use like this:

```
<div class="ui dropdown" suiDropdown>
    <div class="menu" suiDropdownMenu>
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let task of taskList">
        your item
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Full Documentation: https://edcarroll.github.io/ng2-semantic-ui/#/modules/dropdown

Comment: This is not a solution. Did you understand the question fully? UI dropdown doesn't work under `*ngFor` directive.